# Files are showing selected file after opening the dialog box in jfilechooser multi file chooser enabled

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am dealing with this swing component JfileChooser . I am selecting multiple file and then clicked ok .
After that if i again open to select the file it is showing me the previous selected file which i dont want . 
I want previous directory to be maintained but not the previous files .It gives very Bad User experience .

Here is the code Snippet what i have written.

```
    JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();   
        private void fileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_fileButtonActionPerformed
            fileopen.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File[] file = fileopen.getSelectedFiles();
                fileText.setText(file[0].getAbsolutePath());
                for( int i =1;i < file.length;i++)
                {
                    fileText.append("||");       
                    fileText.append(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }else {
                log.info("File access cancelled by user.");
        }       

    }//GEN-LAST:event_fileButtonActionPerformed
```

I tried with those setcurrentdirecotory and all . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me the code what you have tried with setcurrentdirectory ?

Comment: File currentDirectory = fileopen.getCurrentDirectory();
         fileopen.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
         fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(currentDirectory);

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: for better you can try this fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new File("D:\\ somefolder"));

Comment: this wont solve the problem as i want previous selected folder . But my issue is i am getting previous selected files in highlighted mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a new instance of `JFileChooser` each time you need it or call [`setSelectedFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) and pass it `null`

## Updated

So, I had a quick look at the `setSelectedFile` and `setSelectedFiles` methods and they should be clearing the selection and the "file name" field, but it doesn't seem to be working for me on Mac OS, so it's likely a look and feel issue.

What I tend to do is cheat.  I store the last directory value in the `Preferences` API, I do this because it's super easy and it also means that the value persists across executions, super helpful.  If you don't want to persist it across executions, you could use a `Map` or `Properties` or some other variable, that's up to you

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton btn = new JButton("...");
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                String path = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TestPane.class).get("FileAccess.lastSelectedDirectory", null);
                if (path != null) {
                    File filePath = new File(path);
                    if (filePath.exists() && filePath.isDirectory()) {
                        fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(filePath);
                    }
                }
                fileopen.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File[] file = fileopen.getSelectedFiles();
                    System.out.println("You selected " + file.length + " files");
                    Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TestPane.class).put("FileAccess.lastSelectedDirectory", fileopen.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

Comment: It really irritates me when I open a file chooser to discover that I need to navigate from some 'default directory' to deep in a sub-directory structure on a different drive (usually), ***every time*** I go to open (or save) a file! Please for the love of the user, utilize the `setSelectedFiles` option over 'create a new chooser'. `</ end-rant>`

Comment: nope setSelectedfiles is not working i tried fileopen.setSelectedFile(null);

Comment: @AndrewThompson Agreed, I usually seed the last directory into something like `Preferences` and reset it before I open the diaog

Comment: @PraveshBansal `setSelectedFiles` should work, `setSelectedFile` didn't reset the "file name" field for me for some reason.  Anyway, I'd create a new instance of `JFileChooser` each time you need it and simply store the last directory value somewhere

Comment: Yes , above snippet work perfectly fine . thanks a lot @MadProgrammer. one issue is still there . it will always open the last opened location even after restarting the application .If anyone dont want to reopen always on the same location as previous one even after restart then you need to change. i making a fix .

Comment: @PraveshBansal That's kind of a personal choice, I like the fact that it remembers, because I kind of go to/from the same places with many apps, but it's not a hard fix to make to make it session based ;)

Comment: HI , I tried to fix it ..but could not do so in this code .. i want every instance will have a deafult directory.

Comment: Every session or every session?  If you don't want to remember the last directory just take out the `Preferences` code